# algorithm to find n unique randomly selected coordinates

Tags: algorithm, random, unique, bbc-microbit, makecode

I need a way to check that the coordinates of n points bound by ( 0 <= x <= 4 and ( 0 <= y <= 4 )
are unique i.e. no two pints have the same coordinate pairs.

But here is the catch:

The number of points are determined at run time and can be from 1 to n (well let's say <= 10).
The coordinates are selected randomly x = rand(0,4) and y = rand(0,4)

P.S. I am using the makecode block based coding for this project and the LED are on the microbit V1. So the above code has been converted from blocks to python by makecode.

Thanks

```
while index22 < level:  # level determines how many points I need to generate max 10
            listx[index22] = randint(0, 4)
            listy[index22] = randint(0, 4)
            led.plot(listx[index22], listy[index22])  # turns on an LED at the coordinate value
            index22 = index22 + 1
```

I am stumped beyond this..

Comment: So there are typically two approaches for that: 1) you create all possible pairs and use some sort of shuffling (eg Fisher-Yates). 2) you keep a list of already selected pairs and on each draw you check whether the new candidate has already been selected and reselect until you find one that hasn't been selected

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just thinking out loud..I think that would be very memory and cpu intensive option on this little micro-controller (#bbc:microbit)

Comment: Maybe, but if you want random, there is no other way ...

Comment: I do apologize for that BUT know that I am using bbo:Microbit V1 microcontroller which has 16kb RAM and 256kb flash memory and processor speed of 16MHz.

Comment: @SupportUkraine what other ways are there to guarantee uniqueness than either exclude already chosen elements or remember elements that have already feel chosen? You may encode one or the other differently or there may be a library function hiding that from the user. But in the end of the day it always goes down one path or the other.

Comment: @SupportUkraine not really. Just delegating the uniqueness to `random.sample`. when looking at its source, this keeps a list of `selected` elements and just keeps generating random numbers until it hits one, not in this selected set.

Comment: @derpirscher If delegating to `random.sample` makes you unhappy, check out the updated answer below. Note that I propose a solution that is neither of your two categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've only shown python code, I'm operating on the assumption that a possible solution expressed in python will be acceptable as well.

Guaranteeing the uniqueness of integers is easier than guaranteeing uniqueness of multidimensional points. An ancient trick using integer division and modulo arithmetic allows us to map a single integer into unique indices. If we use python's `random.sample()` to get a specified sample without replacement from within the integer range, the following code pops out.

```
import random

level = 10

# there are 25 distinct points in a 5x5 grid, so we
# sample 'level' unique values in the range 0..24
for value in random.sample(range(25), level):
    print(value // 5, value % 5)   # map int to indices
```

I used `print()` so you could confirm the uniqueness of the solutions. Replace the `print()` with a call to `led.plot()` for your application.

---

The approach above can be generalized to non-square grids. We need to identify row and column sizes explicitly, and then the division and modulus operations are performed relative to the column size. The example which follows illustrate this by enumerating a 2x3 and then a 3x2 case. I've isolated the logic in a function and added a bounds check.

```
import random
import sys

def gen_grid(*, rows, cols, level):
    if level > rows * cols:
        print("can't generate more levels than number of elements", file=sys.stderr)
        exit()
    print(f"{rows}x{cols}\n---")
    for value in random.sample(range(rows * cols), level):
        print(value // cols, value % cols)

gen_grid(rows = 2, cols = 3, level = 2 * 3)
print()
gen_grid(rows = 3, cols = 2, level = 2 * 3)
```

which will produce results such as

```
2x3
---
0 2
0 0
1 2
0 1
1 1
1 0

3x2
---
0 0
2 0
1 1
2 1
0 1
1 0
```

Your actual output will vary due to the randomness in the sampling.

This uses python 3 features to enforce named arguments, but could easily be flipped back to use positional notation for python 2 compatibility.

---

If you're concerned that using `random.sample()` is just pushing the challenge under the hood, I agree but would point out that if python is allowed, use of python libraries should be as well. However, if you want a solution which is self-contained and does not use the `random` module, here goes.

One solution that can guarantee unique sequences is to implement a PRNG (pseudo-random number generator) which achieves the maximal cycle length possible over the target range. PRNGs that have a maximal cycle repeat values only after every other value in the range has been enumerated. Implementations for two different PRNG algorithms are given below.

The first is a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) parameterized to have a cycle length of exactly 25.

```
def lcg(seed):
    while True:
        seed = (11 * seed + 13) % 25
        yield seed
```

This will generate unique values in the range [0,...,24] in a shuffled order if called fewer than 26 times. Note that changing the seed value does not change the sequence, it only changes the starting point within the cycle.

The second one is a [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) PRNG. A k-bit generator has a cycle length of 2<sup>k</sup>-1 and produces unique values in the range [1,...,2<sup>k</sup>-1]. With appropriate shift parameters all non-zero values can be generated. (Shifting and XORing zero always results in another zero, hence the exclusion.) To make the results fall in the range [0,...,24], we use k=5, reject values greater than 25, and subtract 1.

```
def xorshift_5bit(seed = 1, upper_limit):
    upper_limit += 1
    while True:
        seed ^= seed << 3
        seed &= 31
        seed ^= seed >> 2
        seed &= 31
        seed ^= seed << 4
        seed &= 31
        if seed < upper_limit:
            yield seed - 1
```

Note that by changing the value of `upper_limit` this can be used for any grid sizes below 31, although the number of rejections will increase for smaller grids. By contrast, the LCG is hard-wired to 25 and new coefficients would have to be determined for other grid sizes.

The resulting integer outcomes can be decomposed into grid indices as described earlier after a slight modification of the original code:

```
def gen_grid(*, rows, cols, level, seed):
    gen_rand = xorshift_5bit(seed, upper_limit = rows * cols)
    for _ in range(level):
        value = next(gen_rand)
        print(value // cols, value % cols)
```

Replace `xorshift_5bit(seed, upper_limit = rows * cols)` with `lcg(seed)` if you like LCGs better. Xorshift uses very efficient bitwise operations, but rejects 6/31 of the outcomes, while the LCG uses the relatively slow modulus operation but keeps all results due to tuning of the parameters. My timings with `hyperfine` showed the two to be indistinguishable.

Note that we no longer need restrict `limit` relative to `rows * cols`. The generators are infinite, we just have to acknowledge that the sequence will start repeating.

Comment: That does make very good point - each integer represents a unique set of coordinates.

Comment: My bad, sorry. Silly me Used cols for `//` and rows for `%` which is of course nonsense ...

Comment: This is a great answer for generic Python but it won't run on the OP's micro:bit, which [doesn't have `random.sample`](https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/random.html). I don't have a micro:bit myself but I got the xorshift version to run on [the MicroPython web demo](https://micropython.org/unicorn/) with some tweaks to function arguments, so that will probably also work on the micro:bit.

Comment: @nekomatic I’ll confess I know nothing about the micro:bit, I got here via the `algorithm` and `random` tags. My own area of expertise here is with random numbers and algorithms related to simulation modeling. I added the PRNG algorithms based on other’s comments, with the idea that that makes the answer self-contained algorithmically. It’s expressed using python because that’s what OP showed, but I could have just as easily used any of several other languages and I assume it should be equally straightforward to translate into whatever works on the micro:bit.